# Loading Images From Previous Email using Reply Template

Tags: vba, outlook

I have done my research on forum but all the solutions that I have tried were not able to rectify the issue.

I am trying to load a reply template using VBA coding but it fails to lead the images from the previous email.

```
Sub OnlinePitchChaserEmail()

    Dim Original As MailItem
    Dim Reply As MailItem

    Set Original = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Reply
    Set Reply = CreateItemFromTemplate("[LOCATION OF TEMPLATE]")

    Reply.HTMLBody = Reply.HTMLBody & Original.HTMLBody
    Reply.Display

    Set Reply = Nothing
    Set Original = Nothing

End Sub
```

Please bear with me as I am a VBA amateur, and the above was an adaptation from somewhere else online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Embedded images are stored as attachments on mail items even if you don't see them on the Outlook UI. Use the [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Attachments.Add) method to attach a file programmatically. Then you must set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property on the attachment appropriately to match the value of the cid attribute:

```
Dim attach as Outlook.Attachment
Dim cid as String

Set attach = objMailItem.Attachments.Add(filepath)

cid = "myImage.png"
NewBody = NewBody + HTMLcode & "<div align=center>" & "<IMG src=cid:" & cid & "</img>" & "</div><br><br>"

attach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", cid)
```

Comment: What `filepath` must be in such a circumstance? I mean, if the attachment of the received email has not been locally saved.

Comment: The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Replies do not load images.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OnlinePitchChaserEmail()

    Dim originalItm As Object
    Dim forwardItm As mailItem
    Dim chaserItm As mailItem

    'Set Original = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Reply
    Set originalItm = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

    If originalItm.Class = olMail Then

        Set forwardItm = originalItm.forward

        Set chaserItm = CreateItemFromTemplate("[LOCATION OF TEMPLATE]")

        chaserItm.HTMLBody = chaserItm.HTMLBody & forwardItm.HTMLBody
        chaserItm.Display

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot simply concatenate two valid HTML documents and expect a valid HTML document back - the two strings must be merged, not concatenated.

Secondly, you will need to save the attachments from the original message and add them to the new message using `MailItem.Attachment.Add`. You woudl also need to copy the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID`, `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_LOCATION`, `PR_ATTACH_LONG_FILENAME` properties (if they are present -you'd need to trap errors).